# Why does such a window appear after authorization and how to fix it, maybe someone came across?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook

Android Studio; Java.
After entering data and authorization, it displays such a window. Authorization takes place in chrome on the emulator, all permissions are approved (including cookies). All the actions of the instructions on the developer's website did.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setPermissions("email");

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();

                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                String name = object.getString("name");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "name");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        TextView nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        nameTextView.setText("Welcome, " + name + "!");
    }
}
```

Here's result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSA5t.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setPermissions("email");

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();

                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                String name = object.getString("name");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "name");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        TextView nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        nameTextView.setText("Welcome, " + name + "!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check facebook developer console. In the error message it is mentioned that your app is not active.